# Create lists from a list by modifying a single item

Tags: python, list

From a certain list of length n, I would like to create n new lists in which in each one of them only one of the elements will change. Below I show example:

the initial list would be:

```
lst = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
```

The output would be three new identical lists (since the length of the initial list is three) in which in each one of them only the value of one element is modified by two:

```
lst1 = [20.4,, 7.3, 12.5]
lst2 = [10.2, 14.6, 12.5]
lst3  = [10.2, 7.3, 25.0]
```

so far I have created this code but it gives me error:

```
lst = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
lists = [[] for i in range(len(lst))]
for i in lists:
    i.append(lst)
    for j in i:
        lists[i] = lists[i] * 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just edited the question with what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
lst = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
lists = [[j*2 if k==i else j for k,j in enumerate(lst)]for i in range(len(lst))]
print(*lists,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[20.4, 7.3, 12.5]
[10.2, 14.6, 12.5]
[10.2, 7.3, 25.0]
```

The closest I could get with your code:

```
st = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
lists = [[] for i in range(len(lst))]
for j,i in enumerate(lists):
    lst[j] *= 2
    i.append(lst[:]) #note I am creating a complete new list object & appending it
    lst[j] /= 2
print(lists)
```

Might be the best, this one:

```
lst = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
lists = [lst[:i]+[lst[i]*2]+lst[i+1:]for i in range(len(lst))]
print(*lists,sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy would be a good choice here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = [10.2, 7.3, 12.5]
>>> a = np.array(lst)
>>> f = np.eye(len(a)) + 1
>>> a * f
array([[20.4,  7.3, 12.5],
       [10.2, 14.6, 12.5],
       [10.2,  7.3, 25. ]])
```